# Keep model made with TFIDF for predicting new content using Scikit for Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

this is a sentiment analysis model made with tf-idf for feature extraction
i want to know how can i save this model and reuse it.
i tried saving it this way but when i load it , do same pre-processing on the test text and fit_transform on it it gave an error that the model expected X numbers of features but got Y

this is how i saved it

```
filename = "model.joblib"
joblib.dump(model, filename)
```

and this is the code for my tf-idf model

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

processed_text = ['List of pre-processed text'] 
y = ['List of labels']
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(processed_text).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

text_classifier = BernoulliNB()
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = text_classifier.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test, predictions))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

edit:
just to exact where to put every line
so after:

```
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
```

then

```
tfidf_obj = tfidfconverter.fit(processed_text)//this is what will be used again
joblib.dump(tfidf_obj, 'tf-idf.joblib')
```

then you do the rest of the steps you will save the classifier after training as well so after:

```
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

put
joblib.dump(model, "classifier.joblib")
now when you want to predict any text

```
tf_idf_converter = joblib.load("tf-idf.joblib")
classifier = joblib.load("classifier.joblib")
```

now u have List of sentences to predict

```
sent = []
classifier.predict(tf_idf_converter.transform(sent))
```

now print that for a list of sentiments for each sentece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first fit `tfidf` to your training set using:

```
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
tfidf_obj = tfidfconverter.fit(processed_text)
```

Then find a way to store the `tfidf_obj` for instance using `pickle` or `joblib` e.g:

```
joblib.dump(tfidf_obj, filename)
```

Then load the saved `tfidf_obj` and apply `transform` only on your test set

```
loaded_tfidf = joblib.load(filename)
test_new = loaded_tfidf.transform(X_test)
```